# Declaring a RandomAccessFile object inside a try block gives resource leak warning but declaring it outside does not?

Tags: java, try-catch, randomaccessfile, resource-leak

This is my code:

```
try {
    RandomAccessFile srcFile = new RandomAccessFile("src.txt", "rw");
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code gives me a warning that the `RandomAccessFile` object srcFile is never closed.

But if I modify my code and declare the srcFile outside the try block (as in the code below), the warning goes away.

```
RandomAccessFile srcFile;
try {
    srcFile = new RandomAccessFile("src.txt", "rw");
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why does this happen, since I'm not doing `srcFile.close();` in any case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract from [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm&resultof=%22avoiding%22%20%22avoid%22%20%22resource%22%20%22resourc%22%20%22leaks%22%20%22leak%22%20):

> If a resource is stored in a field, no single method is considered as
>   responsible for closing; no problem is reported.

I assume this is what is happening when declaring `srcFile` outside of the scope of the `try`. This implies that eclipse compiler cannot assume that the resource needs to be closed, because I may still be referenced outside of the scope in was created in.

Since JDK 1.7 you can solve this with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (RandomAccessFile srcFile =  new RandomAccessFile("src.txt", "rw")) {
    //Do something with srcFile
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that `srcFile` will be closed automatically after the try has been executed.